# Program crash after dnSpy compilation

Tags: .net, dll, dnspy, de4dot

I'm new to dnSpy and there's a program I want to debug, I deobfuscated the .dll in de4dot and then opened it in dnSpy to debug. I tried compiling some method. no compilation error, saved it. And ran the program, result in a crash. BUT there's someone who tried the same on his pc but the program works well. I don't know why.

Tried to just compile a random method in the .dll without changing anything, but still the same. The program crashed. But when I let the program run without a compilation in dnSpy it works. Why ? Someone even tried the same step as I did, his program works but mine doesn't. I tried using x86, x64, netframework, ... on different version but none works. Can someone tell me what's my problem ?
I'm using Windows 10 x64 20h2. I've got dotnet 4.8 and 3.5 installed with SDK 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. It was the deobfuscation process with de4dot that went wrong.